# Autocomplete using Javascript - How is the value passed

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, return-value, onkeyup

I am learning to do autocomplete using Javascript.

This is the example code I am using, it works, I need to understand the flow of it.

When you enter JO in the input tag, the option for 'john doe' is shown

```js
// variables
var input = document.querySelector('#autocomplete-input');
var people = ['john doe', 'maria', 'paul', 'george', 'jimmy'];
var results;

// functions
function autocomplete(val) {
  var people_return = [];

  for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
     if (val === people[i].slice(0, val.length)) {
      people_return.push(people[i]);

    }
  }

  return people_return;
}

// events
input.onkeyup = function(e) {
  input_val = this.value; 

  if (input_val.length > 0) {
    var people_to_show = [];
    autocomplete_results = document.getElementById("autocomplete-results");
    autocomplete_results.innerHTML = '';
    people_to_show = autocomplete(input_val); 
    
    for (i = 0; i < people_to_show.length; i++) {
      autocomplete_results.innerHTML += '<li>' + people_to_show[i] + '</li>';

    }
    autocomplete_results.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    people_to_show = [];
    autocomplete_results.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="autocomplete-container">  
  <input type="text" autofocus="true" name="autofocus sample" placeholder="search people" id="autocomplete-input"></input>
  <ul id="autocomplete-results">
  </ul>
</div>
```

My questions are: (this is to understand the flow - I'm new to Javascript)

- input_val is not declared as variable, but still gets the value - How
- first onkeyup value has to go to autocomplete function 
  and then to come back to it with the array matching the criteria. - How is this done

I have attached an image with the flow - remarks in red is how I understood the flow, the one's in blue are the answer's I'm looking for. [image: Image of What is required]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a value to a variable that hasn't been declared, it will automatically become a global variable.

As for the autocomplete function, it gets called via:

```
people_to_show = autocomplete(input_val);
```

The return value from `autocomplete()` is the value that gets assigned to `people_to_show`

`input_val` comes from `this.value` where `this` is the input element. The `e` passed into the function is not used by the code, though you could use it like `e.target.value`. As the event gets passed in anyway, you can use `event.target.value`. See my code where I've removed the `e`.

`results` is not used in your code

```js
// variables
var input = document.querySelector('#autocomplete-input');
var people = ['john doe', 'maria', 'paul', 'george', 'jimmy'];
var results;

// functions
function autocomplete(val) {
  var people_return = [];

  for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
     if (val === people[i].slice(0, val.length)) {
      people_return.push(people[i]);

    }
  }

  return people_return;
}

// events
input.onkeyup = function() {
  input_val = event.target.value; 

  if (input_val.length > 0) {
    var people_to_show = [];
    autocomplete_results = document.getElementById("autocomplete-results");
    autocomplete_results.innerHTML = '';
    people_to_show = autocomplete(input_val); 
    
    for (i = 0; i < people_to_show.length; i++) {
      autocomplete_results.innerHTML += '<li>' + people_to_show[i] + '</li>';

    }
    autocomplete_results.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    people_to_show = [];
    autocomplete_results.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="autocomplete-container">  
  <input type="text" autofocus="true" name="autofocus sample" placeholder="search people" id="autocomplete-input"></input>
  <ul id="autocomplete-results">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, with both the explanations getting to understand js better. thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Inside the function do a `console.log(this, event)` then expands the objects to get more insights

Comment: how does it decide that people_to_show = autocmplete(input_val) is e or the returned value?

Comment: They are 2 different things: `event` (or `e` when using the original code and then using e.target.value) is the event object that's used inside the anonymous function which is executed after the keyup event. Only `input_val` uses it. `people_to_show` only takes the value returned by `autocomplete(input_val)`.

Comment: So, if you had an empty input and type `j`, then `event.target.value` will be `j`,  `input_val` will be `j`, and `people_to_show` will be whatever is returned from calling `autocomplete("j")`. Inside `autocomplete` `val` will be `j` (all strings);

Answer (score 1):

1. `var results;` Not in use you can remove it
2. `e` in `function(e)` is object of current event
3. `input_val = this.value;` Yes it is a variable you can write in front of it.
4. The code which give value to that function is this line `people_to_show = autocomplete(input_val);`. Here we called the  autocomplete function and pass the value after that the return statement gives the array which is stored to `people_to_show` variable.

[image]

This is how the process is working

Comment: So - first on keypress - the value is assigned to input_val - then from people_to_show = autocmplete(input_val) the function autocomplete(val) gets activated where val will have the value of input_val, then the array of result will be moved back to people_to_show? Is that right

Comment: Yes it is... :)

Comment: thank you , but how does it decide that people_to_show = autocmplete(input_val) is e or the returned value?

Comment: The `returned` value is stored. Nothing has done with `e`

Comment: so first the value (JO) from keypress is sent to function though people_to_show then it awaits the value to be returned from the function to move to  autocomplete_results.innerHTML += '<li>' + people_to_show[i] + '</li>'; - is this right

Comment: keypress is sent to function though `autocomplete(input_val)` which return an array of matching results then the array is assigned to the `people_to_show`. After that in the for loop it is appended to  `autocomplete_results`